# redirect all the requests to api server with nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm using Nginx as a reverse proxy to redirect api request to one my server. Unfortunately it is not working properly

what I'm trying to achieve is to proxy all requests like `/api/v1/*` to `http://my-api-server/api/v1/*`

here is the rule I have written

```
location /api/v1/ {
   proxy_pass http://my-api-server/api/v1/
}
```

but it doesn't work. any idea?

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
location /api/v1/ {
   proxy_pass http://my-api-server
}
```

In `proxy_pass` directive, if you specify the URI which is `/api/v1/` in your case, all matched URIs will be replaced as the exactly specified one `/api/v1/` but not `/api/v1/*`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `proxy_redirect` attribute:

```
location /api/v1 {
    proxy_redirect  http://my-api-server/  /api/v1;
    proxy_pass http://my-api-server;
}
```

Comment: **proxy_redirect** " " Sets the text that should be changed in the “Location” and “Refresh” header fields of a proxied server response. Suppose a proxied server returned the header field “Location: ht tp://localhost:8000/two/some/uri/”. The directive

    `proxy_redirect http://localhost:8000/two/ http://frontend/one/;`

will rewrite this string to “Location: ht tp://frontend/one/some/uri/”.

A server name may be omitted in the replacement string:

    `proxy_redirect http://localhost:8000/two/ /;`

then the primary server’s name and port, if different from 80, will be inserted. " "