# httpclient request start late to load with angular 5

Tags: angular, rest, httpclient, angular5

I have build an app with angular 5 which is working fine except the loading data from rest api ( using httpclient ). When I load app it takes time to load the modules which is around 3 seconds. I have coded to get data from rest API in initializer as follows in a service

```
load(): Promise<any> {
         this._appLoadData = null;
         return this.http
            .get<Response>(this.apiUrl+'appload-new')
            .map((res: Response) => res)
            .toPromise()
            .then((data: any) => this._appLoadData = data.response.data)
            .catch((err: any) => Promise.resolve());
   }
```

and called this load() function in app.module file

```
export function initilizerServiceFactory(initilizerService: InitilizerService): Function {
  return () => initilizerService.load();
}
```

As I am using httpclient ( angular 5 ) it sends OPTIONS request first which hits after 10 seconds of appload and then has a 300ms wait time which results overall delay to get output api. as my app structure is dependent upon this api data it takes around 20 seconds to show the html on page.

I check for other solutions but didnt get the exact solution for the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can make api request's to same server as where the angular app is hosted and then reverse proxy all `/api` requests to your api server. This way you can avoid the `options` request.

Comment: API' s are hosted on same server but on another port (8080) as they are build with golang , not sure how to make it. do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Even if different ports, it will still be considered as CORS, therefore you need to proxy them internally from whichever server you are using to serve angular app. For nginx, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558204/redirect-all-the-requests-to-api-server-with-nginx

Comment: What server you are using for serving angular app ?

Comment: its build with cli and hosted on aws ec2 instance

Comment: So check out reverse proxy with aws. The server must be nginx IMO.

Comment: I have apache 2 on server , have a wordpress site running on instance too ( php ) , never did proxy before with any server so not sure how to do it with apache 2

Comment: You will have to google it out. But thats the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use App Shell (a prerendered entry point) or full Angular Universal SSR and/or a Service Worker to get a quicker first meaningful paint.

Search for App Shell and Angular SW, it's pretty easy to set all that up with NG CLI.

Comment: The problem does not seem to be booting time. Its the options request which is the overkill

Comment: If you had Universal, you could make the initial request on server without an options request.

Comment: You are suggesting him to change his architecture. He probably wants solution with existing architecture. But I agree, this is helpful

Comment: JSONP may be worth trying too, as a quick easy fix, if the server supports that